# Counting number of length k non-overlapping paths on an $n \times n$ grid

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose we have a square grid of size $n \times n$, where each node is connected to its immediate neighbors (up, down, left, right, and the four diagonals when they exist). I'd like to count all of the non-overlapping paths of length k, that is, paths that don't re-use edges (although re-visiting the same node is allowed as long as one arrives and leaves the node via different edges as the first time). In terms of the real world, this corresponds roughly to counting the number of possible passcodes on an android phone, which is how I first thought of the question.

If we didn't impose this non-overlapping constraint, the number of paths would simply be given by summing up all elements of the kth power of the adjacency matrix $A$; but I'm not sure adapting that approach would be useful here. I've also toyed around with the idea of formulating it as a dynamic programming problem, but have had no headway there so far.

I'm looking for either a formula for the number of such paths, or an algorithm to compute such a quantity - the number of paths is approximately $O(8^kn^2)$, so preferably something faster than that.

Comment: The term of art here is "self-avoiding walk" (usually this refers to a walk which never repeats vertices but I think we can pass to the line graph). They are quite difficult to count but there are interesting applications to physics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk

Comment: Also the sequence for $n = 3$ is on the OEIS which might have some relevant references: http://oeis.org/A163889

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yikes, it seems like the translation to the line graph is going to be insane. Just for a $3\times3$ grid you're going from $9$ vertices to $20$ vertices, and in general from $v$ vertices to $4v^2-6v+2$ vertices...